# fatal: write error: No space left on device fatal: index-pack failed only when git cloning via jenkins over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, git

I have a Jenkins server that is trying to run a git clone command on a Development environment server. When the command is run manually over ssh the there is no issue, but when the command is executed by Jenkins on the environment server I get the error:

```
Receiving objects:  99% (7975/8014), 236.00 MiB | 3.75 MiB/s
fatal: write error: No space left on device
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I've ran git gc and git prune on the repo, a df -h shows plenty of space as well as a df -hi. Any help or suggestions of what to do next would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have different partitions? Guess: Jenkins is using a one path for temporary files, on a partition with little space left, while the manual command uses a different path, with plenty of space left.

Comment: Hi @dirkt that was essentially the issue. I've posted the resolution below

Answer (score 1):

For some strange reason the resolution was to have Jenkins CD into the branch you wanted to clone to, and then execute the original git clone command.

```
MY_DIR=/some/folder
mkdir $MY_DIR #verifying the dir exists
cd $MY_DIR; git clone repo.git $MY_DIR
```

My theory is that by default Jenkins mounts to the root of the server and clones there then moves the repo to the final destination folder. If the root partition is too small for the repo this may cause issues due to the clone command being ran in this working directory.